# The client with object id does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/listKeys/action' over scope

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-rbac, azure-ai

I created a new Azure AI Services resource in a Resource Group. I have Contributor access in the Resource Group that contains this Azure AI Service resource.

My problem is I can't list keys with this az cli command. I'm already logged in with az login.

`az cognitiveservices account keys list --name alper-azure-ai-service --resource-group alper-playground`

I'm getting this error message:
*(AuthorizationFailed) The client 'alper.silistre@{myCompanyEmail}' with object id '{myObjectId}' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/listKeys/action' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscriptionObjectId}/resourceGroups/alper-playground/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/alper-azure-ai-service' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.*

I can access Keys and Endpoint section from Azure Portal:

[image]

We can also see in the IAM that I am Contributor from RG (inherited):

[image]

Now, it's clear that Contributor already has 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/listKeys/action':

[image]

So, I'm not sure what I'm missing here, since I should be able to list keys with az cli command. I definitely have Contributor access inherited from the Resource Group.

For reference, I'm following this Microsoft Learn exercise: https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-services/Instructions/Exercises/02-ai-services-security.html

Comment: Hi Aplha, Try refreshing the credentials.

Comment: Hi, refreshing credentials didn't help. But I explicitly put my --subscription {subscriptionName} into az cli command, and it worked. I believe the cli error was misleading since it gives AuthorizationFailed error instead of ResourceGroupNotFound. I realised this by trying different commands like 'az cognitiveservices account show'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem here by trying different az cli commands under az cognitiveservices. For example, when I run this `az cognitiveservices account show --name alper-azure-ai-service --resource-group alper-playground'` it gives me this error:

```
(ResourceGroupNotFound) Resource group 'alper-playground' could not be found.
Code: ResourceGroupNotFound
Message: Resource group 'alper-playground' could not be found.
```

This gave me the idea to specifically put ***--subscription*** into my original command. So when I run the original cli command with this:
`az cognitiveservices account keys list --subscription {mySubscriptionName} --name alper-azure-ai-service --resource-group alper-playground` it worked.

The interesting thing here is that while `az cognitiveservices account show` is giving ResourceGroupNotFound error, `az cognitiveservices account keys list` gives AuthorizationFailed error, which in my opinion is confusing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding a specific subscription fixed it for me as well. Could not find this information anywhere else.